# What is the purpose of RabbitMQ AMQP Java client shutdown handlers?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

The [RabbitMQ documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#shutdown) presents how to add a shutdown listener and when the listener is called but I fail to see on what purpose the handler is for. Seems that all the Java examples (including https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials) out there ignore shutdown handlers. In which cases should I prefer shutdown listener over simply catching `ShutdownSignalException` (and `IOException`) exception ?

Another puzzling issue is that where the control flow goes when the handler has finished.

Potentially relevant related SO questions:

- [What is the best way to safely end a java application with running RabbitMQ consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699669)
- [Using RabbitMQ (Java client), is there a way to determine if network connection is closed during consume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472278)

Answer (score 2):

The main use of a `ShutdownListener` i've seen is to do automatic reconnection. You listen for a shutdown, and when it happens, try to reconnect.

For example, this is the basis of [rabbitmq-ha-client](https://github.com/joshdevins/rabbitmq-ha-client), where it is done in [HaConnectionFactory.HaShutdownListener](https://github.com/joshdevins/rabbitmq-ha-client/blob/8b2ca8c6e37eefdc26ad907ebdd73383bdac3d01/src/main/java/net/joshdevins/rabbitmq/client/ha/HaConnectionFactory.java#L76).